# Rails 3 - Helping with a Commenting Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @commentable= context_object()
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))

    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private  

  def context_object
    params[:constraint][:context_type].singularize.classify.constantize.find( context_id )
  end

  def context_id
    params["#{ params[:constraint][:context_type].singularize }_id"]
  end

end
```

This commenting module has served me well but I ran into a hitch this morning, possibly because of my use of nested resources. Essentially, I now have a URL like:

```
/projects/3/albums/6/attachments/84
```

When I comment on that page, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project without an ID):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:102:in `context_object'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

My routes file looks like:

```
resources :projects do
  resources : albums do
    resources :attachments
  end
end

resources :attachments do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy],
              :constraint => {:context_type => "conversations"}
end
```

Any ideas on how I can get the commenting module to play nicely with commenting on `project>Album>Attachment` ?

Thanks for the input,

Comment: I edited your post for code readability. Could you please clarify why do you resource comments nested on attachments outside de projects > album hierarchy? Do you need to GET /attachments and comment on them? Have you tried to resource comments below attachments on projects > albums > attachments ?

Comment: @tomeduarte thanks! that's a good point. So I'll get rid of that. I suppose it would make more sense to resource comments in the nested resource (i'm still new at rails)... I tried that but get an error: "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `attachment_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x10302bd50>:0x103018610>):" I'll update my question above with the new resource path. what do you?

Comment: ok Stack overflow won't let me edit, that's a pain. Here it is pasted (eck)   resources :groups do
    resources :albums do
      resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy], :constraint => {:context_type => "albums"}      
      resources :attachments do
        resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy], :constraint => {:context_type => "attachments"}
      end
    end
  end

Comment: ok that got it to work -yea! Go ahead and post an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: I was already posting it so it wouldn't be buried here in the comments. :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer in order not to clutter the comments to the original question.

Since you don't have the requirement to keep attachments available via `/attachments` - making the second resources block useless, do something like this:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :albums do
    resources :attachments do
      resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy],
                           :constraint => {:context_type => "conversations"}
    end
  end
end
```

That's going to change your routes helpers (_path and _url), go through your controller(s) and view(s) and change them to reflect your new helpers.

Specifically, `attachment_comments_path` becomes `project_album_attachment_comments_path`.

The full list of routes for those models can be viewed by running `rake routes` in a console. I'd also recommend you take a closer look to the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).